# Get Only Max Value in A specific month

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I want to get the most recent submitted entry based on submitted date column.

Each month, each account have a submitted scores, but sometimes they have to resubmit, so we want to capture only the scores with the most recent submitted date.

it was working for other accounts, there are times that my formula is still not capturing the most recent

Update: Still no answer, still cannot exclude the earlier submitted score from the latest submitted score, even with QueryMax

```
=arrayformula(QUERY(Sheet1!A:Q,"Select MAX(N),A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,O,P,Q group by A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,O,P,Q",-1))
```

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sM2YH.png)

[image: Sample Data]

[Required Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zeet1.png)

[image: Required Output]

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yVw37CrkSVNKxVZnRhhB18Yu5XcapJRbPVJwwraozmQ/edit?usp=sharing) Link for Spreadsheets

Comment: Link for sheets updated

Answer (score 0):

```
=QUERY(A2:F, 
 "select max(C),A,B,D,E,F 
  where C is not null 
  group by A,B,D,E,F 
  label max(C)''", 0)
```

[image: 0]

**note:** as you can notice row 8 and row 9 are not identical so there is no grouping in output

Comment: It's still capturing multiple entries for a specific date, we need to completely exclude the first entry. and also achieved scores changes on the 2nd submission. On the one you posted have the same score thats why they are being excluded

Comment: Hi, on the metrics column its still showing duplicate metrics instead of showing the one with max submitted date [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yVw37CrkSVNKxVZnRhhB18Yu5XcapJRbPVJwwraozmQ/edit?usp=sharing)